# forbid certain (most) routes if not logged in

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm using Ember for my whole site, even the static pages.

I have a devise api setup, with a user.new, user.login and user.edit in order to create, login or edit an existing account.

Any user can just go to

```
http://hostname/user/edit
```

to see the edit screen. I would realy like to make this only possible if a user is logged in. If not that route should for example redirect to the login page.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a `redirect` inside your route. In there you can conditionally check to see if the user is logged in. If they aren't, then you can transition somewhere else.

See the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/) for more about redirection.

### Update

Here is an example from an `AuthenticatedRoute` that I use. For routes that I was to be authenticated, I just subclass from this one.

```
var AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),
  ...

  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get('session').get('token'))) {
      this.get('flashNotification').notify({
        title: "You need to sign in first."
      });
      return this.transitionTo('sign-in');
    }
  },
```

Hopefully that gives some good direction.

If you need more resources, check out:

- [Embercasts](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1)
- [Ember Screencasts](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/85-authenticated-routes) - I haven't seen this one (since it is behind the paywall, but their videos seem to be pretty useful.

Comment: could you please write a minimal example? i've read the article you redirected to but doing what you described still is a bit of a mystery.

Comment: @qknight - I've updated my answer to include an example. Hopefully that puts you in the right direction. The `if` statement is where you want to do w/e check you need to check to see if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: The screencast recommends mixins, but like you said, extended routes are better. Here is a second tutorial: https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/11/09/best-practices-extend-or-mixin

It's about the difference between mixins end extend, but has an example at the end.